# How to run a main class from a GUI Jbutton?

Tags: class, jbutton, actionlistener

I've created a main class (class file). As fas as i'm concerned, it works properly. Now, i'm creating a GUI which contains a button to launch that class file. How do I write the code for the actionListener in order to run mainProgram class?

This is the main class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainProgram
{
  public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{

//Declare variables            
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);  // Scanner used for user input 
BufferedReader inputQuote;
BufferedReader inputTheme;
BufferedReader inputCharacterAnalysis;
BufferedReader inputSignificance;
BufferedReader inputPlotEnhancement;
BufferedReader inputSpeaker;

String [][] quotes;
String text;
int quoteSelection;
int analysisSelection;
int howMany=0;
int count;

  //Count the number of lines in a text file
  FileReader fr = new FileReader ("CrucibleQuotations.txt");
  LineNumberReader ln = new LineNumberReader (fr);
  while (ln.readLine() != null)
  {
    howMany++;
  }

  //import information from the text file 
  inputQuote = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("CrucibleQuotations.txt"));
  inputTheme = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("CrucibleTheme.txt"));
  inputCharacterAnalysis = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("CrucibleCharacterAnalysis.txt"));
  inputSignificance = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("CrucibleSignificance.txt"));
  inputPlotEnhancement = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("CruciblePlotEnhancement.txt"));
  inputSpeaker = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("CrucibleSpeaker.txt"));

  //Create array based on how many quotes available in the text file
  quotes = new String [howMany][6];

  //Store quote information in the array and display the list of quotations
  for (int i=0; i<howMany; i++)
  {
    quotes [i][0] = inputQuote.readLine();
    System.out.println (i+1 + ") " + quotes [i][0]);
    quotes [i][1] = inputTheme.readLine();
    quotes [i][2] = inputCharacterAnalysis.readLine();
    quotes [i][3] = inputSignificance.readLine();
    quotes [i][4] = inputPlotEnhancement.readLine();
    quotes [i][5] = inputSpeaker.readLine();
  }

  //Ask user to choose the quote they want to analyze
  System.out.println ("Choose a quotation by inputting the number. If the quotation you would like to analyse is unavailable, you may create your own by entering the number 0. ");    
  quoteSelection = in.nextInt ();

  if (quoteSelection!=0)
  {
    //Show user selections to analyze
    System.out.println ("Choose your analysis");
    System.out.println ("1. Theme");
    System.out.println ("2. Character Analysis");
    System.out.println ("3. Significance");
    System.out.println ("4. Plot Enhancement");
    System.out.println ("5. Speaker");
    analysisSelection = in.nextInt ();

    //Display the analysis
    if (analysisSelection <= 5 || analysisSelection > 0)
    {
      System.out.println (quotes [quoteSelection-1][analysisSelection]);
    }
  }
```

This would be my GUI class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class GUI 
{    
  public GUI()
  {    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Quotes");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    cButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
         try{
         MainProgram.main (new String[]);
         } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
  });
  }

public static void main (String [] args)
{
  new GUI();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember to call

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

or your JFrame will not be shown.

As for the ActionListener code, you've to add [0] for the String Array dimension such as:

```
  cButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                MainProgram.main(new String[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```